# Jquery Script for Google like POP Up images on Mouse Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was looking for some Jquery plugin which will show the images thumbnail in a bigger image and with the info. related to it. Like we search in Google images and get the nice looking effect of image in bigger size. May be someone have know the plugin or some good suggestion.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi Darin, I was not sure how it works but thank you for pointing out and I have accepted the answers.

Answer (score 1):

There is a beautiful working solution [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7412302/59913).

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/HmTrw/).

Answer (score 1):

A gPop jquery plugin:

[**DEMO**](http://vanamco.com/jquery.gpop/demo.html?utm_source=StackOverflow&utm_medium=post&utm_campaign=blogging)


[**Download plugin on Github**](https://github.com/vnmc/jquery.gpop)