# Pop Images like Google Images

Tags: jquery, popup, thumbnails

[image]

Is there any jQuery plugin or CSS technique to achieve this pop effect like google images?

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```css
#images{
    padding:30px;
}
#images img{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    height:100px;
    margin:5px;
    transition:0.3s;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px #fff;
}
#images img:hover{
    z-index:2;
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
#images img:hover:after{
    content: attr(title);
}
```

```html
<div id="images">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/180x120/000/fff" alt=""/>
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/175x104/f0f/fff" alt=""/>
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x100/a3d/fff" alt=""/>
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/278x125/cf5/fff" alt=""/>
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/199x120/e46/fff" alt=""/>
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/207x480/361/fff" alt="" />
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/400x107/081/fff" alt="" />
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/50x40/cc3/fff" alt="" />
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/700x500/233/fff" alt="" />
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x120/a26/fff" alt="" />
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/341x177/f10/fff" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Nooo don't need a tooltip. Have you tried google image search?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan want to ask some help

Comment: I tried your example but I can't get it to work. I am getting an error in firebug console : "$j("#images img").ibox is not a function". In my index.php, I have called the .js file which contains the pluggin and beneath "$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#images img').ibox();
});" as in the demo. 
I am really new to the jQuery world, I may miss something obvious!

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same thing and had to build a scalable plugin. What was important for me was it scaled within the Wapper or browser like google.

Here is the plugin with a demo

[**DEMO**](http://vanamco.com/jquery.gpop/demo.html?utm_source=StackOverflow&utm_medium=post&utm_campaign=blogging)


[**Download plugin on Github**](https://github.com/vnmc/jquery.gpop)

I hope this helps

Comment: thanks for your work ! I was looking for soemthing scalable ! great great great !

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of jQuery plugins available for this

**[Thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/)**

**[LightBox](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/)**

**[FancyBox](http://fancybox.net/)**

**[FaceBox](https://github.com/defunkt/facebox)**

**[NyroModal](http://nyromodal.nyrodev.com/)**

**[PiroBox](http://www.pirolab.it/pirobox/)**

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option for a mouseover preview type plugin: [imgpreview](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/new-jquery-plugin-imgpreview/)

There's also this, check the second demo:  http://cssglobe.com/post/1695/easiest-tooltip-and-image-preview-using-jquery

[Beautytips](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/bt) may also be of some use, it seems quite flexible.  The Netflix style box is quite nice.

Comment: Nooo don't need a tooltip. Have you tried google image search? – Nimbuz just now edit

Comment: I'm very familiar with GIS.  Check out the demo for imgpreview: http://james.padolsey.com/demos/imgPreview/full/  Towards the bottom, it gets a lot more preview and a lot less tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

See this from google code:

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-image-hover/