# Image Hover Zoom like Google Images

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, hover, zooming

I wrote some `jquery` code (from one video tutorial) to make mousehover zoom effect like in google pictures.
I want to add some delay before zoom (0.5-1 sec), but I don't know how to do that!!!
I've tried a lot of methods with `delay()` or `setTimeout()`, but nothing helps!!!
I do not know why...
Here is the javascript code:

```
    $(function(){

        $.fn.popOut=function(user_opts){            
            return this.each(function(){

                var opts=$.extend({
                    useId:"poppedOut",
                    padding:20,
                    border:0,
                    speed:200
                },user_opts);

                $(this).mouseover(function(){
                    // kill any instance of this already
                    $("#"+opts.useId).remove();

                    // make a copy of the hovered guy
                    var $div=$(this).clone();

                    // setup for prelim stuff
                    $div.css({
                        "position":"absolute",
                        "border":opts.border,
                        "top":$(this).offset().top,
                        "left":$(this).offset().left,
                        "-moz-box-shadow":"0px 0px 12px black",
                        "-webkit-box-shadow":"0px 0px 12px black",
                        "z-index":"99"
                    });

                    // store all of the old props so it can be animate back
                    $div.attr("id",opts.useId)
                        .attr("oldWidth",$(this).width())
                        .attr("oldHeight",$(this).height())
                        .attr("oldTop",$(this).offset().top)
                        .attr("oldLeft",$(this).offset().left)
                        .attr("oldPadding",$(this).css("padding"));

                    // put this guy on the page
                    $("body").prepend($div);

                    // animate the div outward
                    $div.animate({
                        "top":$(this).offset().top-Math.abs($(this).height()-opts.height),
                        "left":$(this).offset().left-opts.padding,
                        "height":opts.height,
                        "padding":opts.padding
                    },opts.speed);

                    // loop through each selector and animate it to its css object
                    for(var eachSelector in opts.selectors){
                        var selectorObject=opts.selectors[eachSelector];
                        for(var jquerySelector in selectorObject){
                            var cssObject=selectorObject[jquerySelector];
                            $div.find(jquerySelector).animate(cssObject,opts.speed);
                        }
                    }

                    $div.mouseleave(function(){
                        $("#"+opts.useId).animate({
                            width:$(this).attr("oldWidth"),
                            height:$(this).attr("oldHeight"),
                            top:$(this).attr("oldTop"),
                            left:$(this).attr("oldLeft"),
                            padding:$(this).attr("oldPadding")
                        },0,function(){
                            $(this).remove();
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        };
        $(".productBox").popOut({
            height:300,
            border:"1px solid #333",
            selectors:[{".productDescription":{
                    height:150
                }
            }]
        });
    });
```

And example HTML code:

```
    <div class="productBox" style="width:300px;height:235px;margin-right:10px;float:left;background-color:#fff;">
    <div class="productImage" style="width:200px;height:116px;overflow:hidden;">
        <a href="#"><img src="/home/ponomar/plakat5.jpg" width="100%"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="productContent" style="float:left;">
        <div class="productTitle" style="height:29px;">Product title</div>
        <div class="productDescription" style="height:70px;">Here is description of the product.</div>
        <div class="buyButton" style="margin-top:0;float:left;"><a href="#">Buy this!</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="productBox" style="width:200px;height:235px;margin-right:10px;float:left;background-color:#fff;">
    <div class="productImage" style="width:200px;height:116px;overflow:hidden;">
        <a href="#"><img src="/home/ponomar/plakat5.jpg" width="100%"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="productContent" style="float:left;">
        <div class="productTitle" style="height:29px;">Product title</div>
        <div class="productDescription" style="height:70px;">Here is description of the product.</div>
        <div class="buyButton" style="margin-top:0;float:left;"><a href="#">Buy this!</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me to do that? besides, I think it is very useful script.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you're looking for : [hoverIntent jQuery Plug-in](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html)

Comment: You just have to download the plug-in and replace your "mouseover" with the "hoverIntent" from the plug-in.

Your line with "mouseover should looks like something like this :

$(this).hoverIntent(makeTall, makeShort,function(){

I think, never use it

Comment: I did how you said, but zoom effect dissappeared at all... But thanks anyway!

Comment: There is one service that permits editting javascript code online with immediate result. I've added there your code:

http://jsfiddle.net/Cu5uc/2/

Could you help me to make delay here?

Answer (score 0):

The best example can be found at [Pop Images like Google Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411393/pop-images-like-google-images/7412302#7412302)

[Also take a look at the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/HmTrw/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy the cloned object to your original div then you need to just following the steps:

add id to your original div & the following code above the respective code:

```
var old_box = $div.attr('id');

$div.attr("id", opts.useId)
    .attr("oldWidth", $(this).width())
    .attr("oldHeight", $(this).height())
    .attr("oldTop", $(this).offset().top)
    .attr("oldLeft", $(this).offset().left)
    .attr("oldPadding", $(this).css("padding"));
```

add the following code above the mouseleave event:

```
$div.click(
    function() {
        $("#" + old_box).html($(this).html());
        $(this).remove();
    }
);
```