# stop div resizing parent div using css

Tags: css, resize

### http://jsfiddle.net/ETkkR/

```
<div id="Blog1">
    <div class="post">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/180x120/000/fff" alt="Image 1" title="This is my first image"/>
        <div class="post-info">
            <span>post title post title post title</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/175x104/f0f/fff" alt="Image 2" title="The second one is pretty"/>
                <div class="post-info">
            <span>post title post title post title</span>
        </div>
    </div>        
</div>​
```

The div.post-info in some cases(images of width greater than the div.post-info content) fits the div.post parent however sometimes the width of the div.post-info is greater having an affect on the parent div.post by resizing it. how can i make the div.post-info fit the width of the div.parent and not resizing it if it is greater.

### my css

```
#Blog1{
    padding:10px;
}
#Blog1 .post{
    border:1px solid #000000;
    margin:3px;
    text-align:center;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1
}
.post img{
    height:100px;
}
.post .post-info{
    text-align:left;
}
.post .post-info span{
    word-wrap:break-word;
}​
```

### Edit

**YOU CAN CHANGE THE ELEMENTS AS LONG AS THE CONTENT REMAINS SAME TO CREATE A SOLUTION**
people keep giving solutions which are not suitable for what i'm asking...what i need is for the child div .post-info to not be a greater width than that of the .post parent div

Comment: Just a question: you don't want to increase the height but achieve something like the element has `overflow:hidden;` right? You should tell us what you want to achieve and don't want.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a demo, but you should really explain: **do you want the height to be variable ?**

**[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ETkkR/7/)**

edited CSS (only changed elements):

```
#Blog1 .post{
    border:1px solid #000000;
    margin:3px;
    text-align:center;
    position: relative;
    display:block;         /**/
    float:left;            /**/
    overflow:hidden;       /**/
    padding-bottom:24px;   /**/
}
.post .post-info span{
    position:absolute;     /**/
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

P.S: this question associates me to an old answer of mine :)
[Pop Images like Google Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411393/pop-images-like-google-images)
If you need help ... I'm here

Comment: I know i discovered it two days ago it's brilliant i've personally made some edits to the plugin, ITS GOOOD, but i need a fallback for users with javascript disabled.

Comment: :) thanks! I was so surprised seeing your fiddle! :) Ok, now tell me what you think about my demo and my answer --- and my question - Cause I'm afraid if you try to expand the height of the container, than the all-in result could be a bit messy (as it depends on the description length.)

Comment: I've come up with an alternative solution and once im done with the styling i'll share it with you

Comment: your answer is what is helped me to come up with a solution though so i've accepted ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11533/discussion-between-yusaf-and-roko-c-buljan)

Comment: See answer here about using zero width and min-width properties to solve this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19005373/prevent-paragraph-from-increasing-the-width-of-a-floated-parent/36092670#36092670

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work with the following change to your CSS:

```
.post .post-info span{
    display: block;
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ETkkR/3/).

Reasoning:

- `display: block;` allows a `width` (and therefore `max-width`) to be assigned to the element.
- `max-width: 90%;` to ensure that the element's maximum width is less than the width of the parent, allowing some space between the content of the element and the borders of the parent.
- `margin: 0 auto;` horizontally centres the element within its parent.

Comment: A lot of white spaces between images may be. Not good. They all must be everywhere one size

Answer (score 0):

```
#Blog1 .post{
    border:1px solid #000000;
    margin:3px;
    text-align:center;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
    max-width: 200px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

This solution will not however work in IE6 I think.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the div `.post` width to 100%, and `.post-info` width to 100%:

```
#Blog1 .post {
  width: 100%;
}

.post-info {
  width: 100%;
}
```

I believe this will make the div `.post-info` relative to its parent div.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as the OP and the solution for me was to set

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

I couldn't repro the behaviour in a fiddle, but just adding the above to the inner element resolved it in my app, so I hope that helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

Try the css property `max-width`

Comment: I know that but if i set a max-width property the text will not be the same width as the content in the parent div if it is greater