# Jquery Image hover effect Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I checked this link of S.O : [Pop Images like Google Images](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7412302/59913)

And tried to setup the image hover effect.

Everything worked fine when i tested it in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/HmTrw/)

```
// ibox image zoomer plugin // roXon

(function($) {
    $.fn.ibox = function() {

        // set zoom ratio //
        resize = 20;
        ////////////////////
        var img = this;
        img.parent().append('<div id="ibox" />');
        var ibox = $('#ibox');
        var elX = 0;
        var elY = 0;

        img.each(function() {
            var el = $(this);

            el.mouseenter(function() {
                ibox.html('');
                var elH = el.height();
                elX = el.position().left - 6; // 6 = CSS#ibox padding+border
                elY = el.position().top - 6;
                var h = el.height();
                var w = el.width();
                var wh;
                checkwh = (h < w) ? (wh = (w / h * resize) / 2) : (wh = (w * resize / h) / 2);

                $(this).clone().prependTo(ibox);
                ibox.css({
                    top: elY + 'px',
                    left: elX + 'px'
                });

                ibox.stop().fadeTo(200, 1, function() {
                    $(this).animate({top: '-='+(resize/2), left:'-='+wh},400).children('img').animate({height:'+='+resize},400);
                });
            });

            ibox.mouseleave(function() {
                ibox.html('').hide();
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.item').ibox();
});
```

But when i added it to my site, I get the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Window] is not a function
    $('.hovermore').ibox();
```

I guess its because of other jquery effects in the site.

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Did you remember to link to the jQuery library on the page this is on? Also, I have had conflicts between code libraries which resulted in similar errors, try replacing $ with the word jQuery in your code, e.x. jQuery('.hovermore').ibox

Comment: @Mike It worked after i added jQuery instead of $. But i see that the hover image effect works only in the first div container. And In other containers, The effect is not working. Also its having another hover effect which doesn't work when this hover effect works. btw http://windows7themer.com its my site. So please guide me on this and also how to change the width of image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.item').ibox();
});
```

or

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.item').ibox();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your support.

It worked after i added jQuery instead of $.

But i see that the hover image effect works only in the first div container.

And In other containers, The effect is not working.

Also its having another hover effect which doesn't work when this hover effect works.

btw windows7themer.com its my site. So please guide me on this and also how to change the width of image.

regards, Rias

Answer (score 0):

Try starting your code with:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
```

Comment: Sorry I dont understand why my answer wont work and HADI's will

Comment: Ah, I was looking at the first piece of code, not really a good question but whatever.

Answer (score 0):

that's because you forgot to load jQuery :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you included jQuery on your page before calling `$('.hovermore').ibox();`?

Also, I don't think it should matter, but also make sure you're using the latest version of jQuery.

Can you post a link to the page where it doesn't work so we can see all of the code?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include the jQuery library.

Visit [this](http://jsbin.com/ifefop/edit#javascript,html,live) demo, go to SAVE -> DOWNLOAD and look at the downloaded file.

http://jsbin.com/ifefop/edit#javascript,html,live

Your document should have:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And if you placed the script in an external file:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/ibox.js"></script>
```

Comment: It worked after i added jQuery instead of $. But i see that the hover image effect works only in the first div container. And In other containers, The effect is not working. Also its having another hover effect which doesn't work when this hover effect works. btw windows7themer.com its my site. So please guide me on this and also how to change the width of image.