# jquery image zoom like google image search

Tags: jquery

I need to do the same thing  from this post [Pop Images like Google Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411393/pop-images-like-google-images)
But i need to add as same as google image search ie the on hover the image title need to be displayed . I am from java and new to jquery so please help me http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/HmTrw/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just after the line `ibox.html('');` (around line 20 in the JS) add this line:

```
jQuery('<div />').text(this.title).appendTo(ibox);
```

You will also want to add some CSS.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I needed more than attribute `title`, my images structure is as next:

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
    <li>
        <div class="thumbnail">
             <img src="/images/200X150.gif" alt="200X150" />
             <div class="caption" style="display:none">
                  HTML Goes here
             </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    ....
</ul>
```

you'll need to update plugin [ibox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411393/pop-images-like-google-images)
after:

```
el.mouseenter(function() {
    ibox.html('');
```

add this:

```
$('#ibox').append('<div class="ibox-caption">'+$(this).siblings('.caption').html()+'</div>');
```

and the css for .ibox-caption should have the same image width:

```
.ibox-caption {
    width: 200px;
}
```