# "Uncrop" an image on hover with jquery

Tags: jquery, image, effects

I'm sure someone must have written a plugin for this already, but I was wondering if anyone knows of one that will allow a cropped version of an image to be shown on a page, and hovering over it shows the uncropped version?

More information:

Ideally I'd like to store the uncropped image on the server, and have the page initially show the cropped version (i.e could be cropped with css). On mouseover, the image "grows" to its full, uncropped size in front of all the other content (i.e. the surrounding elements don't move)

Comment: Are you dealing with two separate files, one that is cropped and one that is not? Seems like you could just use jQuery hover() and change the src attribute of the img.

Comment: It would be helpful to add screenshots or mockups showing the default state and the hover state. Either that or a more detailed description of how it should behave.

Comment: Like Google Images used to be, except the thumbnails are cropped instead of scaled. Related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411393 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383893 (note: the "cropping" part may require customizing an existing plugin).

Comment: If you need control over where the cropping occurs for each image (to make them more presentable), you'll need to either have custom CSS/JS for each image, or separate images for the cropped thumbnails. For separate images, it may be simpler to just use a generic popup plugin, like jQuery Tools.